# Как нажать клавишу enter, если её нет на клавиатуре?

Tags: клавиатура

Сегодня ремонтировал нетбук ASUS, и после сборки отказала клавиша enter. К сожалению, она там одна, и необходимо её нажимать в стандартном загрузчике.

Каким образом её можно нажать комбинацией, чтобы не идти за новой клавиатурой?

Comment: Попробуйте подключить USB-клавиатуру.

Comment: Нет возможности, я в деревне.

Comment: Нечем проверить, но, помнится, можно было нажимать `Alt` и при нажатом, на цифровой клавиатуре ввести ASCII-код нужного символа. `Alt + 0,1, 5, 1` для длинного тире. Может, так же можно и Enter? `Alt + 0, 0, 1, 3` или без нулей..

Comment: Да, @Sergiks прав, Alt + 0,0,1,3

Comment: @tCode, разве это не фича windows? Сомневаюсь, что в загрузчике сработает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да... вряд ли сработает

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вчера я хорошо покопался и Windows XP и загрузчике в моём случае срабатывает Ctrl+m